Will "relationship" be read as "relationship with other people" when it's not being modified?
I want to ask if we need to say something like relationships with others to make it clear that we are not talking about relationships with things like money? We only need to say relationships and it will be read as relationships with other people?

For some, anger can become a problem and can affect a person's daily
life and relationships.  (Vice)


Yes, without modifiers, the word relationships (plural) is typically assumed to mean relationships with other people - especially close friends and family. If you want to talk about someone's relationship with an inanimate object, an idea, or an animal, you would need to be more specific.
Notably, in common usage, the singular relationship used without modifiers is typically assumed to mean a romantic and/or sexual relationship. For example:

How is your relationship going?

This is specifically asking how the listener's relationship with their romantic partner (like a boyfriend, girlfriend, or spouse) is doing.
To talk about a different singular relationship, you would specify, such as by saying:

How is your relationship with your mom?


It depends on context. If you were talking about database design and used the word "relationship", I'd most likely assume you were talking about a relationship between two database tables. If you were talking about your personal life and you used the word "relationship", I'd generally assume you were talking about a relationship with another person. I'd be unlikely to think you meant your relationship to money or to your car unless the context called for it.
